# Using StealJS to load Bower components lacking a bower.json file

Tags: bower, stealjs

I am using the StealJS + Bower integration in my application, but a couple of my Bower components (including [`es6-collections`](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections)) do not contain a bower.json file. Because `es6-collections` is one of the dependencies in my project's bower.json file, StealJS tries to load the `es6-collections` component's bower.json file, cannot find it because it does not exist, and complains: `Unable to load the bower.json for es6-collections.` I tried using `System.config({ path: { 'es6-collections': '...' } })` to notify StealJS of the path to the script to use when loading `es6-collections`, but that does not help. What can I do to get StealJS to load this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumptions

So I am going to make a few assumptions:

- you are using steal from bower
- you are "bower install"'ing es6-collections from github directly
- you are implicitly using the [system-bower plugin](https://github.com/stealjs/system-bower) by using the HTML `<script src="bower_components/steal/steal.js" main="main"></script>` to load your "main" file

If these things seem mostly *true-ish* then you may just have to **add some configuration** in your `bower.json` file to silence the error/warning and have everything work as expected.

#### Explanation:

So because the system-bower plugin (which you are using implicitly because steal detects it is being loaded from a `bower_components` directory) uses the components `bower.json` files to determine entry points, so in this case the error/warning comes from not being able to find es6-collections `bower.json` file.

#### Solution:

So we just need to tell System (used by steal) where to find that module and that it can stop looking for it's `bower.json` file.

We can do that by adding a `"system"` property to the bower.json and adding some configuration data like this...

```
"system": {
  "paths": {
    "es6-collections": "bower_components/es6-collections/index.js"
  },
  "bowerIgnore": ["es6-collections"],
  "meta": {
    "es6-collections": {
      "format": "global"
    }
  }
}
```

- The `paths` configuration there, tells System where to find the module
- The `bowerIgnore` array tells `system-bower` to not look for the `bower.json` for that module
- and the `meta` config is there to tell System to treat this module like it's a script that is going to add to the global object (window in the browser), which you should probably do for this particular module because of the way es6-collections was written: it exports an empty object if it has nothing to pollyfill so you can't use the exported object, best to just use it as if it was a global module.

For more information on all these things...

http://stealjs.com/docs/bower.html

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/wiki/Meta-Configuration

http://stealjs.com/docs/steal.html

Just to have a working example here https://gist.github.com/BigAB/c108bb0860c9cfee3d6a are three files you can copy-paste/clone and then do a `bower install` and see it working.